# Linq inner join using Split

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, join

Actually,I'm using `2 tables` like `GREETING_TRANSACTIONS` and `COUNTRIES`.

In the `COUNTRIES` table I'm maintaining list of `CountryShortCode` and `CountryFullName`.

While sending the `Greetings`,I'm saving `CountryCodes` in `,` separated way in `GREETING_TRANSACTIONS`.For Example : `IN,MY,CN` for India, Malaysia and China.

Now what I'm doing is : First I'm getting the list of `GREETING_TRANSACTIONS` using this query

```
var Messages =
(
    from u in obj.GREETING_TRANSACTIONS
    orderby u.SENT_DATE descending
    select new
    {
        u.ID,
        u.COUNTRIES,
        u.TITLE,
        u.MESSAGE,
        u.SENT_DATE,
        u.GREETING_TYPE,
        u.CATEGORY_NAME
    }
).ToList();
```

and later getting each item and `splitting` the `COUNTRIES` column and getting the related `CountryFullName` using `CountryShortCode` and preparing a `DataTable` and binding to the `GridView`.

is it possible to do everything in a single query using Joins?

may be something like :

```
var Messages1 =
(
    from u in obj.GREETING_TRANSACTIONS
    join c in obj.COUNTRY_MASTER
            on u.COUNTRIES.Split(',') equals c.COUNTRY_SHORTNAME
    orderby u.SENT_DATE descending
    select new
    {
        u.ID,
        u.COUNTRIES,
        u.TITLE,
        u.MESSAGE,
        u.SENT_DATE,
        u.GREETING_TYPE,
        u.CATEGORY_NAME,
        c.COUNTRY_FULLNAME
    }
).ToList();
```

I'm new to Linq and found this very difficult.

is it possible to query data by taking comma separated ShortCodes and generating Fullnames?

do I need to use sub queries?

Comment: yes you can do it this way

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: yeah.but for looping all the countries,it is taking long time like 45 seconds.is it possible to write a single query using Joins?

Comment: Use of comma separated fields in a db is USUALLY a design flaw. You should have a relationship table between greetings and countries, as it's a many to many relationship.

Comment: as @RaphaëlAlthaus mentioned if you will have M2M then you can use LINQ to query without using joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you can't do a join query on a split. You need to make a `SelectMany` out of it.

So, given that the list of countries would be really quite small then the easy way is to create a look-up.

Keep your `Messages` query an then do this:

```
var lookup = obj.COUNTRY_MASTER
    .ToDictionary(x => x.COUNTRY_SHORTNAME, x => x.COUNTRY_FULLNAME);

var Messages1 =
(
    from m in Messages
    from c in m.COUNTRIES.Split(',')
    where lookup.ContainsKey(c)
    orderby m.SENT_DATE descending
    select new
    {
        m.ID,
        m.COUNTRIES,
        m.TITLE,
        m.MESSAGE,
        m.SENT_DATE,
        m.GREETING_TYPE,
        m.CATEGORY_NAME,
        COUNTRY_FULLNAME = lookup[c],
    }
).ToList();
```

---

As per the comment below:

```
var Messages1 =
(
    from m in Messages
    orderby m.SENT_DATE descending
    select new
    {
        m.ID,
        m.COUNTRIES,
        m.TITLE,
        m.MESSAGE,
        m.SENT_DATE,
        m.GREETING_TYPE,
        m.CATEGORY_NAME,
        COUNTRY_FULLNAME = String.Join(
            ", ",
            m.COUNTRIES
                .Split(',')
                .Where(x => lookup.ContainsKey(x))
                .Select(x => lookup[x])),
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: This is unlikely to work, given the OP is likely using either Linq2SQL Linq2EF or Linq2nH given that they used the term "Table".

Comment: @Aron - No, it works just fine. The OP has a `.ToList()` on his first query and the `.ToDictionary()` will bring the look-up into memory too. I use this all the time.

Comment: Ah...fair play...but now the issue is that you are doing all your filtering in memory and without indices. PS you'd likely want to pass a stringcomparer into the `ToDictionary`.

Comment: @Aron - Given the small size of the countries list and the fact the the OP wants a "select many" type query this will improve performance as it's likely that less data will go across the wire. Why the string comparer?

Comment: Likely that you would want `CaseInsensitiveCultureInvariant`, also...stripping whitespaces would be a good idea too..

Comment: is it possible to join the COUNTRY_FULLNAME with comma separated where ID is same? Now I'm getting all the CountryNames in separate records,But I want the CountryFullnames to be joined with comma separated and to be in 1 record

Comment: @Enigmativity : Such a Clear and perfect answer.Increased a lot of performance :)

Comment: @RealSteel - You'd be surprised how much performance you can get by bringing the data in to memory and then querying against it rather than try to get the data in a single complex query.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Thanks for your suggestion.I'm new to this development.Can you tell me what do you mean by bringing data in to memory?

Comment: @RealSteel - Calls to `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, `.ToDictionary(...)` & `.ToLookup(...)` force the query to run and bring the data into memory. Otherwise linq calls are deferred until their actual use, not when they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using a comma separated list as a data field is not a good idea. You need an extra many-to-many table linking `GREETING_TRANSACTIONS` and `COUNTRIES`.